# Django Matching query does not exist

Tags: django

I cant figure out what is happening here. I want to retrieve an object then add a user to myobject.followers. But I can't get it to work. I am pretty new to Django. What is happening here?

models.py

```
class SubNetwork(models.Model):
    sub_name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    followers = models.ManyToManyField(User)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.sub_name

    def number_of_followers(self):
        self.number = self.followers.count()
        return self.number

    def number_of_posts(self):
        self.total_posts = self.fishingreport_set.count()
        return self.total_posts
```

views.py

```
def sub(request, sub_name):
    subnetwork = SubNetwork.objects.get(sub_name=sub_name)
    fishing_report = FishingReport.objects.filter(sub_network=subnetwork.id).order_by('-pub_date')

    paginator = Paginator(fishing_report, 10)

    page = request.GET.get('page')
    try:
        reports = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        reports = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        reports = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)
    return render(request, 'subnetwork/sub.html', {'subnetwork': subnetwork,
                                                   'reports': reports})

    def follow(request, pk):
        if request.method == 'POST':
            report = SubNetwork.objects.get(id=pk)
            return redirect('sub/subs/')
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^subs/', views.all_subs, name="all_subs"),
    url(r'^(?P<sub_name>\w+)', views.sub, name='sub_name'),
    url(r'^follow/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)', views.follow, name='follow'),
]
```

html

```
 <form method="POST" action="{% url 'subnetworks:follow' sub.id %}">
   {% csrf_token %}
   <input type="submit" value="UP">
 </form>
```

error
Environment:

Request Method: POST

```
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/sub/follow/1

Django Version: 1.10.5
Python Version: 3.6.0
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django.contrib.humanize',
 'TheFishNetwork',
 'accounts',
 'subnetwork',
 'posts',
 'markdownify']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback:

File "/home/swapnil/python_envs/fishenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  39.             response = get_response(request)

File "/home/swapnil/python_envs/fishenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  187.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/home/swapnil/python_envs/fishenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  185.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/home/swapnil/PycharmProjects/fishnetwork/subnetwork/views.py" in sub
  13.     subnetwork = SubNetwork.objects.get(sub_name=sub_name)

File "/home/swapnil/python_envs/fishenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py" in manager_method
  85.                 return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)

File "/home/swapnil/python_envs/fishenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in get
  385.                 self.model._meta.object_name

Exception Type: DoesNotExist at /sub/follow/1
Exception Value: SubNetwork matching query does not exist.
```

main urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^accounts/', include('accounts.urls')),
    url(r'^reports/', include('posts.urls')),
    url(r'^sub/', include('subnetwork.urls'),),
    url(r'^^(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$$', home_page, name='user_front'),
]
```

Comment: The error is coming from `sub` view. Add `sub` view code to question.

Comment: You haven't posted your main `urls.py` also. Possibly this might be happening: Form submission redirects to `sub/subs/` and `url(r'^(?P<sub_name>\w+)'...)` pattern matches the url and hence `sub` view is called. But inside `sub` view, Django couldn't find `SubNetwork` with mathcing `sub_name`. Hence the `DoesNotExist` exception.

Comment: added main `urls.py` and `sub` view

Comment: Add a `$` in the end of *application's* url regexes in urls.py. Then check if you're still getting the error.

Comment: added the `$` to the end of `name=sub_name` url and I did not get the error. Thank you.